# Print every alternate column in row in a text file

Tags: awk, command-line

I have a comma separated file. I would like to print every alternate columns into a new row.

Example input file:

```
Name : John, Age : 30, DOB : 30-Oct-2018
```

Example output:

```
Name,Age,DOB  
John,30,30-Oct-2018
```

Comment: You should show your attempt

Comment: awk -F'[:,]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) printf("%s%s", $i,(i+2>NF)?ORS:OFS)}' OFS=,              This command works, but header is missing

Comment: please edit your question by adding your attempt

Answer (score 1):

non-`awk` solution

```
$ sed 's/[,:]/\n/g;s/ //g' file | pr -3ts,

Name,Age,DOB
John,30,30-Oct-2018
```

Comment: assumes 3 fields; you can make it dynamic by counting first but at that point probably easier to do it all in `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:]]*[:,][[:blank:]]*"}
      { for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf (i==1?"":",") $i; print "" }
      { for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf (i==1?"":",") $i; print "" }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Your example and output:

```
$ awk -F', ' '/ : / { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( match($i,/ : /) ) { linekeys=linekeys substr($i,1,RSTART-1) ","; linevalues=linevalues substr($i,RSTART+RLENGTH) ","; } } print(substr(linekeys,1,length(linekeys)-1)); print(substr(linevalues,1,length(linevalues)-1)); linekeys=""; linevalues=""; }' file.txt
Name,Age,DOB
John,30,30-Oct-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general idea you could use to implement a solution.

Using awk's `split` function.

1. Split the entire line into an array `rows` with the row delimiter (`", "`), and save the number of rows.
2. Split each row into an array `cols` with the column delimiter (`" : "`), and save the number of columns.  And iterate over the column values and store them into a table, indexed by row and column, e.g. `data[row","col]`.
3. Finally, iterate over first number of columns and then number of of rows, printing `data[row","col]`.